# On the existence of a sequence of positive continuous functions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Does there exist a sequence $(f_n)$ of positive continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ such that

$f_n(x) \rightarrow \infty$ if and only if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

If $f_n(x) \rightarrow \infty$ is replaced by $f_n(x)$ is unbounded, then the answer is no. This follows from Baire's theorem.

Thank you,

Answer (score 6):

See the paper, First Class Functions, in the American Mathematical Monthly 98 (March, 1991) 237-240.

EDIT: Let $f_n(x)=n$ if $x=p/q$ with $q\le n$, $f_n(x)=0$ if $x=(p/q)\pm n^{-4}$ with $q\le n$, and let $f_n$ be piecewise linear between these points. So $f_n$ is continuous, mostly zero, but with a sharp spike at each rational. Clearly $f_n(x)$ goes to infinity with $n$ at all rational $x$. If $x$ is irrational and has only finitely many rational approximations $p/q$ such that $|x-(p/q)|\le q^{-4}$ (and this is all $x$ save a set of measure zero), then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n$ sufficiently large. If $x$ has infinitely many rational approximations with $|x-(p/q)|\le q^{-4}$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for most $n$ (those that are far from a $q$ which gives a good approximation, and those $q$ are guaranteed to be few and far between), but is occasionally quite large, so $f_n(x)$ has no limit, finite or infinite.

Comment: Can you remind us of the author please, Gerry?

Comment: @Robin, I think I do remind you of the author. 

Comment: I know that this is a very old post...but let me try asking. I do not see how to fill the details  to get $f_n(x)=0$ for most $n$ in the last case. In principle having $|x-p/q| \leq q^{-4}$ does not prevent to have $|x-p/q| \leq n^{-4}$ for many $ n \geq q$ until we reach the next good approximation $r/s$. Could you give some more detail?

Comment: @Giorgio, maybe you should post this as a new question.

Comment: Gerry, thank you for your answer. I just found an old paper by Sierpinki which is very clear (and avoids any number theory).

Comment: @Giorgio, good! Maybe you could write up what you found, and where you found it, and post it.

Comment: Actually I got the paper from a later post answered from Willie Wong. I can send the paper to you, if you like to have it.

Comment: @Giorgio, can you just post here the author, title, journal volume year pages? or a link to Willie Wong's post?

Comment: Here is the paper by Sierpinski I am referring to: W. Sierpinski, Sur l'ensemble des points de convergence d'une suite de fonctions continues, Fund. Math. 2(1921), 41-49. It was quoted in an answer by @Willie Wong which I am unable to find again. The paper is very general but specializing to the case of a countable set gives quite a simple construction of the sequence, without using Diophantine approximation.

Comment: @Giorgio, thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 3):

An explicitely wrong solution is as follows: Choose a bijection between $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Q$ and denote by 
$\mathbb Q_n$ the image of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ under this bijection. Choose also a sequence $s_n(x)$ of continuous
functions on $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ with limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n(x)=\infty$
if $x=0$ and with limit $0$ otherwise and consider the sequence of continuous functions $s_n(d(x,\mathbb Q_n))$
where $d(x,\mathbb Q_n)$ denotes the distance of $x$ to the finite set $\mathbb Q_n$
corresponding to the first $n$ rational numbers under the choosen bijection.

The limit is then clearly $\infty$ on rationals. However Malik Younsi objected correctly
that one can say nothing on the limit for irrationals and Myerson's Monthly paper 
states that the limit on irrationals cannot be bounded for all irrationals.

PS: I have rewritten this post, originally starting as "An explicit solution ...",
in order to illustrate the perhaps counterintuitive result of Myerson's Monthly paper.

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't it possible that $s_n(d(x,\mathbb Q_n))$ tends to infinity for some irrational $x$?


Comment: True. One has to choose the sequence $s_n$ suitably in order to avoid this.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible... The paper cited below proves the following result :

There is a sequence of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ whose pointwise limit if finite on $S$ and infinite on the complement of $S$ if and only if $S$ is a $F_{\sigma}$.

But $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ is not a $F_{\sigma}$, so the sequence of functions you're trying to construct cannot exist...

Comment: That is disturbing!

Answer (score 0):

$1_\mathbb{Q}$ is a "double limit" of continuous functions in the sense that we define $f_{nm}(x) = \cos(n!\pi x)^{2m}$ which converges pointwise to $1_\mathbb{Q}$ for $n,m \to \infty$.

Define $g_{nm}(x) = -\log(1-f_{nm}(x))$ which seems to do (close to) what you want.

Only problem is that there might not be a clever way to run through $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ to get a single sequence such that it converges pointwise to $0$ for each irrational $x$.

Comment: @ Henriksen The functions attain the value 1 on a rational for all but finitely many 'n' . Hence these would not give us continuous functions taking (only) rationals to infinity.

Comment: Let me illustrate with $f_3$. $f_3(x)=3$ for $x=0,1/3,1/2,2/3,1$. $f_3(x)=0$ for $x=1/81,1/3±1/81,1/2±1/81,2/3±1/81,1−1/81$. For all other $x$, $0\le x\le1$, connect the dots. So, e.g., $f_3(x)=0$ for all $x$ with $1/81\le x\le1/3−1/81$, whether such $x$ are rational or irrational. Strictly speaking, this only defines $f_3$ on $[0,1]$, but extend it to all of $\bf R$ by making it periodic with period one.

Comment: I'll leave up my last comment, even though Koel has edited out the motivation for it, since it may help anyone else who found the definition of $f_n$ in my answer opaque.